# Is a For Loop always executed at least once?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, language-agnostic

According to my teacher, a for-loop always executes at least once, even if the condition is not met.

Example (like I know it from C++):

```
for (int i=6; i <=5; i++) {
    //irrelevant for this question
}
```

According to her, this loop would execute at least once, yet it does not, or am I missing something? 
Is there any case, no matter what language, where this would execute once? 
To eliminate the thought in advance: yes, it was about for loops, not do-while-loops.

**Edit**:

Thanks for all those quick answers, I guess this case is already closed. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Regarding c++, your teacher is wrong. A `for` loop won't execute at all if the condition is false before the first iteration.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood, and your teacher merely refers to the initialization and condition check? Also, why is this tagged with Python? Python for-loops are not like C++ for-loops.

Comment: only a `do while` loop is guaranteed to run at least once

Comment: Your teacher's statement is complete and utter nonsense, as your test easily demonstrates.

Comment: @BaummitAugen OP is right in doing research beyond testing himself. C++ is notorious in that direct observation is far from sufficient to determine if and how a behavior is defined.

Comment: Gee, here's a thought. Remove the comment, insert a `printf` statement, and compile and run your code. Voila! You know the answer.

Comment: @KenWhite It seems like he did that test, since his question says "yet it does not".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know python has a different for-loop, yet I don't know Python and it could be that she could be wrong regarding Python's for-loop. That's why I tagged it with Python as well.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sure. And I just confirmed that their test does indeed demonstrate that their teacher's statement was nonsense.

Comment: @Klaus9090 don't spam language tags. If your question could be about any language, use [langage-agnostic]. I've gone ahead and edited.

Comment: @Barmar: Then the OP should be going to the teacher, demonstrating that the lesson was wrong, and asking that teacher to explain. (It's what I did when encountering this sort of situation.)

Comment: @KenWhite I did, yet she would not admit she was, now obviously, wrong.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it was not my intention to spam tags. Thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: @Klaus9090 no worries, just giving you a heads up for future questions. It's easy enough to clean up tags.

Comment: @Klaus9090: So you know the answer, the teacher refuses to admit she's wrong... What exactly are you wanting us to do here? Boycott your school?

Comment: @KenWhite That sounds like a great idea

Comment: @KenWhite I just wanted to check if there were cases that I could be missing where she was right.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could say a for-loop is always ***evaluated*** at least once.

But if a for-loop's condition is not met, its block will never execute.

Because you didn't ask about other loops, I won't address those.

Comment: Evaluation in this case means checking if the condition is true or false, right?

Comment: That is, and always will be, correct.

Answer (score 7):

A loop will only execute while its condition is true.  Since a `for` loop and a `while` loop both check the condition before the body is executed they will never execute if the condition is false.

The only loop that will is a `do while` loop.  With a `do while` loop the condition is not evaluated until the end of the loop.  Because of that a `do while` loop will always execute at least once.

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop always makes sure the condition is true before running the program. Whereas, a do-loop runs the program at least once and then checks the condition.

Answer (score 0):

An entry controlled loop will never execute if the condition is `false`, however, exit controlled loop will execute at least once.