# Can I search in an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    <script>
  function multiple(arr) {
    var counter = [];  //counter is the occurrence of a specific element in an array
    var unique = [];   //the actual element in the array
    var found;        //the index showing if the element is already in the counter
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      found = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
        if (unique[j] == arr[i]) {     //
          found = 1;
          counter[j] = counter[j] + 1;
        }
      }
      if (found == 0) {    //if it's the element's first apperance in the array
        unique.push(arr[i]);  
        counter.push(1);
      }
    }
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
      result.push([unique[i], counter[i]]);
    }

    return result;
  }
  console.log(multiple([5,1,5,6,3,4,6]));
</script>
```

My question is about this part:

```
 for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
 if (unique[j] == arr[i]) {
```

But when i=0 and j=0, the array unique is empty. Wouldn't it go undefined during the search? However, this function works. I am wondering why.

Comment: If `unique` is empty `for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {` doesn't run the content of the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932344/is-a-for-loop-always-executed-at-least-once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `for` loop checks its condition before entering the loop body. When `unique` is empty, `unique.length` is `0`, and the answer to the "question" `0<0`? is false (0 is not less than 0), so the loop does not even start.

```
for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
  ...
}
```

runs in a similar way as

```
var j = 0;
while( j < unique.length ) {
  ...
  j++;
}
```

Comment: @JiangYuxin no, it will not cause problems, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: You wrote exactly the same as I've started to type, but you were faster... +1